# WSO2 GREG Roles

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I'm noticing an issue in the role management module. When attempting to create a user with a decreased role-set, say: only having login permission and list permission on the assets. The user is unable to see the "List" sub-menu under the 
"Metadata" menu. Although the "Metadata" menu displays with nothing underneath it.

[image]

[image]

The link is an album with pictures of both the issue and the permissions for that user.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

As descried in the documentation, it is required to have the WS-API permission selected.

Must have missed that in the Roles docs.

Comment: better if you can create a Documentation jira for this. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DOCUMENTATION